# http request from react client server to express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I am a beginner with node js. It is weeks now that I have this problem.

I have my client code written with react, redux and runs it on localhost:3000

My server code is written with express and runs on localhost:8080.

I have a route -

```
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
  res.json('here');  
});
```

When browsing from the browser I can see the response, even when using postman I can see the response.

But when I am making an axios call from the client and want to store it in my redux store, the response I am having is like this -

[screenshot of the response in the client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvkB0.png)

What is happening here??

Comment: You might be getting a Cross Origin Request (CORS) block. This is caused by the browser trying to block unsafe requests to a remote server. You can try this to fix it: http://www.darrenbeck.co.uk/nodejs/react/reacttutorial-part3

Comment: can you post the front end axios code as well. There are a number of things that could be wrong but we cant know without the axios call.

Comment: @Someguy this is not the issue.

Comment: @MattPengelly my axios should work, when doing the call to other server (3rd party) I get the expected response.

Comment: the server was running on port 8080, it made conflicts and when changing it to some other number all is now working.

Comment: @Maayans that was due to a CORS restriction, which you said it wasn't. LOL!